# Thonny shows ImportError

Tags: python, thonny

When i try to open thonny, it shows the following error.

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
 File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
 File
"C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\run.py", line 201, in run_module
  mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name)
 File
"C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\run.py", line 136, in _get_module_details
  raise error("No module named %s" % mod_name)
ImportError: No module named thonny
```

Versions:

- OS: Windows 7 64-bit
- Python: Python 3.8.10(32bit)
- Thonny:4.0.1

Any help in this matter is appreciated.

It used to show more errors back but then i tried installing python separately, which turned out to say that i didn't had the required windows update. So i installed the update and installed python and the errors have been lessened but im still not able to open thonny

Comment: please show the code that created this error: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: actually im not able to open thonny at all